# Flurry error when trying to request ad (Database access disabled)

Tags: android, flurry

Having a hard time in my first flurry integration on Android. This is the code I'm using to connect as documentation states:

```
FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true); 
FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this,"GJTCVGM4XG7PSHSZZTDM");
FlurryAgent.initializeAds(this);
FlurryAgent.enableTestAds(true);


// The following method call will asynchronously
// render a banner in the provided ViewGroup:
FrameLayout fViewGroup= (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.bannerframe) ;
FlurryAgent.getAd(this, "Bottom Banner", fViewGroup,
                                FlurryAdSize.BANNER_BOTTOM, 0);
```

This is producing following log:

```
11-15 21:14:22.380: D/FlurryAgent(2473): Initializing Flurry session
11-15 21:14:22.380: D/FlurryAgent(2473): New session
11-15 21:14:22.390: D/FlurryAgent(2473): Initializing Flurry Ads
11-15 21:14:22.390: D/FlurryAgent(2473): Flurry Ads initialized
11-15 21:14:22.400: I/FlurryAgent(2473): Init'ing ads.
11-15 21:14:22.400: W/FlurryAgent(2473): Cannot identify UDID.
11-15 21:14:22.400: W/Settings(2473): Setting android_id has moved from     android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
11-15 21:14:22.400: I/FlurryAgent(2473): loading persistent data: /data/data   /com.fosfore.flurryintegration/files/.flurryagent.45cf4771
11-15 21:14:22.400: D/FlurryAgent(2473): Loading API key: ****************ZTDM
11-15 21:14:22.400: D/FlurryAgent(2473): Loading session reports
11-15 21:14:22.400: D/FlurryAgent(2473): Persistent file loaded
11-15 21:14:22.400: D/FlurryAgent(2473): generating report
11-15 21:14:22.400: D/FlurryAgent(2473): Sending report to: http://data.flurry.com/aap.do
11-15 21:14:22.910: D/FlurryAgent(2473): Report successful
11-15 21:14:22.960: I/FlurryAgent(2473): Request successful
11-15 21:14:22.980: E/FlurryAgent(2473): Ad request returned errors: 
11-15 21:14:22.980: E/FlurryAgent(2473): Internal Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Database access disabled
11-15 21:14:24.440: I/FlurryAgent(2473): Request successful
11-15 21:14:24.440: W/FlurryAgent(2473): Ad request successful but server delivered no ad units.
```

Could anybody guess what is hapenning? I have an ad space setup with the correct name.

P.D. Using FlurryAgent.isAdAvailable it allways says there isn't any ad available. My ad space is active, have I to do anything else to start receiving ads? I'm not using any mediation at the moment.

THanks in advance.

Comment: have you recied ad? I'm facing issue...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179744/ad-server-responded-but-sent-no-ad-units-in-flurry-in-android

Comment: They fixed my prob. Best thing you can do is contact them through their help desk. Hope it helps.