# "Ad server responded but sent no ad units" in Flurry in android

Tags: android, ads, flurry

I want to integrate Flurry Ad from [here](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Publisher/Code/Android). But I'm facing issue in log..

```
01-06 11:05:28.746: E/FlurryAgent(440): Ad server responded but sent no ad units.
```

http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Publisher/GettingStarted/TechnicalQuickStart/Android

I have created adSpace @ http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Publisher/GettingStarted/SetUp

My code is

```
FlurryAgent.enableTestAds(true);
FrameLayout fViewGroup = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.bannerframe);
if (mContext != null) {
        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(mContext, API_KEY);
        FlurryAgent.setUserId(Utils.getUserId(mContext));
        FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(Debug.DEBUG);
        FlurryAgent.initializeAds(mContext);
    } else {
        Debug.e("", "mContext is null");
    }

FlurryAgent.getAd(Flurry.getContext(), "my adSpace", fViewGroup,
            FlurryAdSize.BANNER_BOTTOM, 0);
```

**Note** :

`"my adSpace"` is replaced with my original ad Space on Flurry.

Help!!!
Thanks.

Comment: Hello @sunshine, did you have any luck with it? I'm having the same issue. Did you find what's wrong? Thanks...

Comment: Yes, I have solved.. Have you read  http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Publisher/GettingStarted/TechnicalQuickStart/Android and you have to wait for getting ad for first time.

Comment: how much time should we wait to receive actual ads and not the test ads?

Comment: How much we need to wait for getting  ad for first time

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this issue:
Find interface function shouldDisplayAd() and change return to true :

```
@Override
public boolean shouldDisplayAd(String arg0, FlurryAdType arg1) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Where is this interface function located?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling enableTestAds() after the call to onStartSession().

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Comment: I already tried this. at that time I did not received. Now it works. reason was adspace. and now flurry does not log anything to server., I don't know

Comment: Why flurry is fighting with context??... :D

Comment: Hi,When phone screen is locked full screen video audio is still running in gingerbread and when screen unlocked video is hanged.