# General Flurry setup and initialization

Tags: android, flurry

I'm building an android application that uses flurry sdk.

I have in my activity the following code:

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FlurryAgent.setVersionName("1.0");
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "XXXXXXXX");
    FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
    FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(true);
    FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
    FlurryAgent.initializeAds(this);

    FrameLayout fViewGroup = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.flurry);
        FlurryAgent.getAd(this, "BANNERNAME", fViewGroup, FlurryAdSize.BANNER_TOP,0);


}
public void onStop()
{
   super.onStop();

       FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);


}
```

So here are my two questions:

1. When trying to run in android below Gingerbread flurry throws exception as it uses String.isEmpty that is not available. Is there a way to overcome this exception?
2. When running in android above Gingerbread, code runs "fine" but does not display the ads. 
   Flurry just prints in LogCat "ad server responded but send no ads units".
   In flurry panel I have created the project, and the adSpace with the same name as in the above code.

**Note**: I've done what is said in this post [“Ad server responded but sent no ad units” in Flurry in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179744/ad-server-responded-but-sent-no-ad-units-in-flurry-in-android) and still neither testads are showing up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your first question, this exception should not be thrown in Android 2.3 or above. Flurry has a fix in the works for this issue, and should be releasing it soon.
On your second question, could you try removing the call to FlurryAgent.initializeAds(FlurrytestActivity.this);? This call should only be necessary if ad pre-caching is enabled in the ad space settings.

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've overcomed the problem of ad server responded but sent no ad units. I've still have some problems with advertisements though. I've contacted Flurry Support :)

Comment: how you overcome the problem?