# What means : "FlurryAgent﹕ Ad server responded but sent no ad units."?

Tags: android, ads, flurry

I try flurry's ads. I followed the instructions in this guide https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/publisher/code/android/#sdk-integration-for-android-integrate-code-for-banner-display=

My Code:

```
private static final String MY_FLURRY_APIKEY="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
RelativeLayout mBanner;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FlurryAgent.init(this, MY_FLURRY_APIKEY);
        mBanner=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.banner);
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this);

        mFlurryAdBanner = new FlurryAdBanner(this, mBanner, "banner1");
        FlurryAdTargeting flurryAdTargeting=new FlurryAdTargeting();
        flurryAdTargeting.setEnableTestAds(false);
        mFlurryAdBanner.setTargeting(flurryAdTargeting);

        mFlurryAdBanner.fetchAndDisplayAd();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
        mFlurryAdBanner.destroy();
    }
```

Advertising sometimes displayed or not.

what means "Ad server responded but sent no ad units."?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179744/ad-server-responded-but-sent-no-ad-units-in-flurry-in-android).

Comment: I'm using in an App DFP, which is something similar. Now no ads are displayed since nobody booked ads for my app. So the ad server response to show no ads. This means that this is not your fault, except you sell the ads yourself. I would contact the advertiser in your case flurry to find out why they don't send ads to your app.