# Flurry Error FlurryAgent: Ad server responded but sent no ad units

Tags: java, android, flurry, flurry-analytics

Hello Guys i am integrating Flurry ad network and trying to show test ads but it gives me following error

```
12-12 11:09:58.669 17082-17627/cpp.eminosoft.com.adserver E/FlurryAgent: Ad server responded but sent no ad units.
12-12 11:09:58.686 17082-17243/cpp.eminosoft.com.adserver E/FlurryAgent: AdRequest: url:https://ads.flurry.com/v16/getAds.do
```

This is my Code

```
 new FlurryAgent.Builder()
            .withLogEnabled(true)
           // .withListener(flurryListener)
            .build(this, Keys.FlurryAPIkey);

    mFlurryAdInterstitial = new FlurryAdInterstitial(this, "TestNew");

    FlurryAdTargeting adTargeting = new FlurryAdTargeting();
    adTargeting.setEnableTestAds(true);
    mFlurryAdInterstitial.setTargeting(adTargeting);
    mFlurryAdInterstitial.fetchAd();


     flurryAdInterstitialListener=new FlurryAdInterstitialListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFetched(FlurryAdInterstitial flurryAdInterstitial) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Flurry Fetched",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mFlurryAdInterstitial.displayAd();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRendered(FlurryAdInterstitial flurryAdInterstitial) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDisplay(FlurryAdInterstitial flurryAdInterstitial) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(FlurryAdInterstitial flurryAdInterstitial) {
            mFlurryAdInterstitial.fetchAd();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAppExit(FlurryAdInterstitial flurryAdInterstitial) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onClicked(FlurryAdInterstitial flurryAdInterstitial) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoCompleted(FlurryAdInterstitial flurryAdInterstitial) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FlurryAdInterstitial flurryAdInterstitial, FlurryAdErrorType flurryAdErrorType, int i) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Flurry not Fetched error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };



    mBanner = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.Flurry_banner);




    mFlurryAdBanner = new FlurryAdBanner(this, mBanner, mAdSpaceName);


    mFlurryAdBanner.fetchAd();
    FlurryAdBannerListener bannerAdListener = new FlurryAdBannerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFetched(FlurryAdBanner adBanner) {
            adBanner.displayAd();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FlurryAdBanner adBanner, FlurryAdErrorType adErrorType, int errorCode)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Flurry Banner Failed To Load",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            adBanner.destroy();
        }
        @Override
        public void onRendered(FlurryAdBanner adBanner) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onShowFullscreen(FlurryAdBanner adBanner) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onCloseFullscreen(FlurryAdBanner adBanner) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onAppExit(FlurryAdBanner adBanner) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onClicked(FlurryAdBanner adBanner) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onVideoCompleted(FlurryAdBanner adBanner) {

        } };
    mFlurryAdBanner.setListener(bannerAdListener);
```

and on button click i am trying to show interstetial and fetch again

```
  mFlurryAdInterstitial.setListener(flurryAdInterstitialListener);
    mFlurryAdInterstitial = new FlurryAdInterstitial(this, mAdSpaceName);
    FlurryAdTargeting adTargeting = new FlurryAdTargeting();
    adTargeting.setEnableTestAds(true);
    mFlurryAdInterstitial.setTargeting(adTargeting);
    mFlurryAdInterstitial.fetchAd();
```

The Flurry session is initialized correctly

I already Looked [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179744/ad-server-responded-but-sent-no-ad-units-in-flurry-in-android) question but not helpful .How Do i get ads To Display ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the problem from coding side, This problem occurs because there are no ads present at the current location ,try changing your phone `VPN` to `US` and see.The ads should start displaying.  If you are still facing the problem you can mail the flurry support team at     `support@flurry.com` .They helped us solving the problem.